# CSS z-index not working in input field

Tags: css

I have an input field with my custom placeholder. I did it custom because of IE & Mozilla issues.

So, basically, there's an input field with an absolute positioned `<span>` element such that it perfectly fits the input field.

However, when I focus on the input field, the focus goes to the span element. I tried using `z-index` but it didn't work. Please help. I just want the cursor to focus on input field rather than the span element.

```css
#placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="position: relative;">
<span id="placeholder">Type and Hit Enter to Search...</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `label` to wrap both elements. You can also adjust some CSS to make the span disappear on the focus:

```css
label {
  position:relative; /*Make the span positioned relatively to the label*/
}
#placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

/*On focus change the z-index*/
input:focus + #placeholder {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<label>
 <input type="text">
 <span id="placeholder">Type and Hit Enter to Search...</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I want to show the placeholder even after input is focused because I am handling it with Javascript. In a nutshell, I just want the cursor to focus on input rather than the placeholder text.

Comment: @Sanjay simply remove the last CSS line I added ;)

Answer (score 2):

[`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is what you need here. It makes element unclickable with pure CSS.

#### `pointer-events` method:

```css
#placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="position: relative;">
<span id="placeholder">Type and Hit Enter to Search...</span>
```

#### Fallback alternative for `<IE11`:

```css
input {
  position: relative;
}

input:hover+span {
  display: none;
}

#placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="position: relative;">
<span id="placeholder">Type and Hit Enter to Search...</span>
```

Comment: Damn! You're a CSS Wizard. Thanks but `pointer-events` is not supported in IE < v11. Do you have any other alternative?

Comment: I have edited my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122539/7059945). Could you please test my *fallback alternative for <IE11*?

Comment: Thanks for your time but I found @TemaniAfif answer a perfect one.